# Ошибка компиляции React

Tags: reactjs, sass

Через npm install sass установила sass, запускаю проект и он выдает такую ошибку, не могу ее решить. Что делать?

```
Failed to compile.
./src/components/Button/Button.module.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./src/components/Button/Button.module.scss)
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
```

Comment: Вроде как просят еще дать команду `npm install node-sass`...

Comment: пробовала но сразу пишет что версия устарела, читала, что node-sass уже не  используют

Answer (score 0):

`node-sass` безнадежно устарел установите SASS Вот так. Хотя использование SASS это дискуссионный вопрос. Если Вы используете CSS модули в React:

```
npm install sass
# or
yarn add sass
```

Мой package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: npm install sass именно так я и делала, пробовала уже удалить папку node_modules и потом заново «npm install» и кеш чистила

Comment: Как Вы сам реакт устанавливали?

Comment: npx create-react-app . --template typescript

Comment: Странно только что установил, и у меня все работает.

Comment: Как Вы импортировали и использовали scss файл в компоненте Button?

Comment: Вот все мои импорты в Button import React,{FC,ReactNode} from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

import styles from "./Button.module.scss";

Comment: @НикаВолкова Я подозреваю, что Ваша проблема из за этого импорта `import classNames from "classnames";`. Попробуйте без этого модуля.